# show MDI child from splitcontainer panel

Tags: c#, mdi, mdichild

I want to first hide childform(frmMenuMasterlist) then show childform(frmMasterlistAdministrationAdd) to MDI parent (frmMain.splitcontainer.panel2). It works fine when the button is on parentform like a masterpage in web, but when I put it in childform, only this.hide() executes. Can anyone help me out in this scenario. Many thanks in advance

```
private void btn_Administration_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        frmMasterlistAdministrationAdd frmMasterlistAdministrationAdd = new frmMasterlistAdministrationAdd();
        frmMasterlistAdministrationAdd.TopLevel = false;
        frmMain frmMain = new frmMain();
        frmMasterlistAdministrationAdd.Parent = frmMain.splitContainer3.Panel2;
        frmMasterlistAdministrationAdd.Show();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
frmMasterlistAdministrationAdd frmMasterlistAdministrationAdd = new frmMasterlistAdministrationAdd();
    frmMasterlistAdministrationAdd.TopLevel = false;
    frmMain frmMain = new frmMain();
    frmMasterlistAdministrationAdd.Parent = frmMain;
    splitContainer3.Panel2.Controles.add(frmMasterlistAdministrationAdd);
    frmMasterlistAdministrationAdd.Show();
```